# In acute angle triangle, prove that $\cos (A-B) \cos (B-C) \cos (C-A)\ge 8\cos A \cos B \cos C$

Tags: trigonometry, inequality, triangles

> In acute angle triangle, prove that 
>   $$\cos (A-B) \cos (B-C) \cos (C-A)\ge 8\cos A \cos B \cos C$$

My progress:

$$\cos(A-B)=2\cos A\cos B+\cos C\ge 2\sqrt{2\cos A\cos B\cos C}$$ 
$$\implies \prod\cos(A-B)\ge 8\left (2\prod \cos A\right )^{\frac 32}$$

Comment: Your inequality is true for all reals $A,$ $B$ and $C$ such that $A+B+C=\pi$.

Comment: Dear Rosenberg please share your solution

Comment: Open please a new topic and I'll show my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$2\sin A\cos(B-C)=\sin2B+\sin2C\ge2\sqrt{\sin2B\sin2C}=4\sqrt{\sin B\cos B\sin C\cos C}$$

As $A,B,C$ are acute, all the trigonometric ratios are $>0$
$$\implies\cos(B-C)\ge?$$

Similarly for $\cos(C-A),\cos(A-B)$